# Can't ping VM from host using NAT mode (both ubuntu)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

I installed LAMP stack on my VM and tried to ping from my VM to host. It works, but whenever I try to ping from host to vm, it doesn't. I need this to finish installation of Drupal7 on my VM server.

Some basic info:

```
Host machine - Ubuntu 16.04 (Desktop)
VM - Ubuntu 12.04 (Server) running on Oracle VirtualMachine
LAMP stack is installed on VM.
Openssh is installed on VM (not sure if its a necessity)
```

**What Im trying to achieve:** Connect to my VM through the IP address in order to install Drupal 7 later on.

**What I did else in order to understand better why this doesn't work:**

- Checked apache2 status
- Checked Openssh status
- Tried pinging from host machine to VM and vice versa. All the packets sent from VM to host were successfully sent. All the packets sent from host to VM were lost, the connection was not made.

When I used cable, I chose Bridged network adapter and I everything was fine, but now, when Im using NAT, it doesn't work

[image: Network settings]

[image: Ifconfig of VM]

[image: Ifconfig of Host]

Comment: There is no NAT when you ping a virtual machine from the host. The two are connected directly. Please post your configuration (including IP addresses and network interface settings on the vm) and a transcript of commands.

Comment: @techraf Edited my post, you can see two images at the end of it.

Comment: Add the host configuration, network configuration and the transcript (asking for the second time).

Comment: Last time I had this, I stopped searching and added a second network adapter in host-only mode.  If the VM needed the Internet, it could go over the NAT, if I needed to connect from my host to the vm, I would use the host-only adapter.  It's a workaround.

Comment: @jawtheshark, when I tried adding other network adapter, it gave me errors and I couldn't start my VM.

Comment: Please don't post images when text is enough. Include the virtual network configuration.

Comment: @techraf might sound stupid, but where can I find that? please bear with me, im begginer :/

Comment: I don't have the GUI now, and the  CLI command `vboxmanage natnetwork list` from the manual is not working. You have to find yourself. From what you posted now, it looks like it shouldn't work either way.

Comment: @jawtheshark - great workaround, and helpful.  I was stuck in a hotel room and my normal bridge didn't work.  Using NAT + host-only to go in got me through the weekend.  Thank you!